# Can't read or write using fopen in windows 7 because of permissions

Tags: c, windows, windows-7, fopen

I've been searching for a while to find this answer but I can't find a solution. Basically I'm trying to read and write to files in the c drive of my computer. However because it is windows 7 it chooses to be a pain in the back side and not give permission to my C program to do it. I have tried running it in administrator mode as well as trying to use different directories.
When the following code is run:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(strIn, "r");
if(fopen(strIn, "r") == NULL)
{ 
    printf("Error: %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    getchar();
}
```

The returning error is  "Error 13 permission is denied". I know that Microsoft don't really like using `fopen` any more as it favours `fopen_s` but I find difficulty in understanding how to implement it and there is a lack of resources on it as well. Is there any way around this problem as it is really setting me back at the moment. Much appreciated,

Jack

Comment: What paths have you tried with? Unicode paths have been an issue with fopen in windows before.

Comment: Well it being inputed as single slashed by the user. For example "C:\dtm100m\" then put in to a char array. Is this what you mean/

Comment: not really. Please list some examples of failed ``strIn``.

Comment: while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) //loop through each file in the directory.
             {
                    //open the file and loop through each line converting it then outputing it into a new file
                    
                    sprintf(strIn,"%s%s",pathStr,ent->d_name);

Comment: print the ``strIn`` and paste the output log here in a comment or in your question.

Comment: Why are you opening your file twice? You should post the code that gives the full context of your problem rather than just this snippet.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is opening the file twice:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(strIn, "r");
if(fopen(strIn, "r") == NULL)  /* Second open, leaks FILE *! */
```

This might cause errors, since Windows can be picky about allowing a file to be opened multiple times. The second line should read:

```
if(fp == NULL)
```

Comment: If I recall correctly the Windows implementation of fopen() opens the file in exclusive mode.